# Drupal business listing a-z indexing requirements

Tags: drupal

I want to render something like below in a view.

==================================================================

View: Car parts (Content type)

```
A | [B] | C | D | E | [F] | [G] | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z

BONNET
FRONT BUMPER
FRONT BAR REINFORCEMENT
GUARD LEFT
GUARD RIGHT
```

==================================================================

How do you create the top A – Z index. The letters in [ ] are anchor links.

Answer (score 0):

I think this discussion could help you: 
https://drupal.org/node/403012